# What is the best way to create periodic tasks with Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to create a periodic task in Rust (period about 50ms). Ideally, I want to specify the scheduling policy and priority of the thread. Is this possible with Rust?

I found this [last example](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.12.0/tokio/time/fn.interval.html) to create a periodic task with the Tokio library. The advantage is that the interval is handled by the library. How does this perform in contrast to a [std::thread](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/) where I implement the interval handling on my own? Are there other useful crates for this purpose?

The idea is that a simple PID controller should be implemented in this task. Other parallel tasks (periodic and aperiodic) are also necessary which should not interrupt or delay the PID controller task. The program runs on as Raspberry 4 with the Raspberry OS.

Comment: yes it is possible. But if you dont show us what did you try we cannot really help you.

Comment: I tried the example with the Tokio library I linked in my question. It works. But my concerns are that some ticks can be missed when I add more tasks that are less important (as far as I know you cannot specify a priority of tasks). I wonder if there is a more performant way to do this.

Comment: Rust's async mechanisms are a form of "cooperative multitasking" and tokio will make a "best effort" to trigger your code at the right time. If other tasks are running, they cannot be pre-empted in order to run your "higher priority" task; this isn't a feature lacking on tokio's side, but a core property of how async code is executed. This may be fine depending on how much jitter is acceptable, but if not, you'd want it on its own thread that you can prioritize, and at that point I'd probably suggest doing it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If setting the priority of threads is your only concern =>

Rust doesn't implement any priority management for threads/tasks as you mentioned. If you would want that feature you could/should use c bindings as in [libc](https://crates.io/crates/libc). An existing crate which wraps the c bindings for priority management is [thread_priority](https://crates.io/crates/thread-priority). Maybe you could take a look at that.

For any "normal" use case of scheduled tasks, the tokio crate should work fine. You are even able to specify the strategy for missed ticks.

If you'd implement that feature yourself, you wouldn't have the thread pool functionality as with the tokio crate, so I wouldn't do that. It would be faster to start up but not as "stable" imo.